# Check if user changes pages

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor, how can you detect if a user exits a page? I'm making a chat room and I want to display who is currently in the room. How would I detect when someone leaves the room?

Comment: This is more complicated than just detecting when a user leaves a page - you also need to detect when a user closes their browser. For the first case, you can use [iron:router's `onStop` hook for your route](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#available-hook-methods). For the second case, you can use the [mizzao:user-status](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status) package.

Comment: This question seems pretty broad. Not necessarily _too_ broad - I don't know enough about Meteor to judge how complex this is - but kind of borderline. Stack Overflow is better for single, well-defined questions than "how do I do this".